# How can I pass data stored in the DOM to the controller using link_to, remote: true and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like to have the following link:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("#{@player1.first_name}_#{@player1.last_name}.jpg",
    alt: "#{@player1.first_name}_#{@player1.last_name}", class: "playerpic"), 
    updatepts_path, :remote => true %>
```

provide data within the DOM to the controller using jQuery, for example:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("#{@player1.first_name}_#{@player1.last_name}.jpg",
    alt: "#{@player1.first_name}_#{@player1.last_name}", class: "playerpic"), 
    updatepts_path, :remote => true,
    data: { matchupID: $('#matchup-id').data(matchupID)) } %>
```

where I've added `data: { matchupID: $('#matchup-id').data(matchupID)) }` to the `link_to` helper. Is this or something comparable possible to do? If so, how would I access the data from the controller, using `params[:data][:matchupID]`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to the updatepts_path for the matchupID in routes, and add the matchupid to the link url created by link_to.

That or just add something like ?matchupID=xxxx to the link if you don't mind the messy url.

Aferall link_to just makes a  tag in the end, its fully capable of being manipulated by javascript after rendering.